# .animate.queue() in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a function which removes answer from the form when it is submited.

The command which removes div.A:

```
target.children("div.A").remove();
```

works for every question, when it is submited. The div is removed.

Then if I replace it with this function to animate the remove command:

```
parent.animate({height: "0"},2000).queue(
          function() { 
              target.children("div.A").remove(); 
          }
```

so it works only once. It animates the remove command for first question, but not for the others.

Using jquery-1.6.2.min.js

How to solve this problem to make it animating every answer?

**Edit:** parent and this is the same Jquery object. The parent.animate() fails.

Comment: Could you give as a little snippet with an example? Maybe using jsfiddle.net

Comment: give us a fiddle so we can help you faster and easy for us.

Comment: OK, I can, but you will miss images (=answers) and link to Jquery jquery-1.6.2.min.js

Comment: Link to JSFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZjX2D/  **Note:** You see numbers instread images so it cannot work properly. You look for submit_ function

Comment: So far I have found that code applied for next div will work any time:     parent.next().animate({height: "auto"},2050).queue(
              function() { $(this).next().css("display", "block");
              console.log("NEXT WORKS");
               }              
              );

Answer (score 0):

```
var submit_ = function (that, parent, target){
    var typ = $(that).attr("name");    
    var id = $(that).attr("id");
    var answerDiv=$(that).parent().parent().children("div.A");
    answerDiv.animate({height: "0"},2000,"swing",
              function() { answerDiv.remove(); } );
}
```

This works